# Javascript Regex - matching opening and closing parenthesis when nested

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex to grab background urls from css:

```
/(@import.*?)?url\(([^)]+)\)/gi
```

This works fine for most cases. However, css in the wild is another matter.  Even though it is not valid, I need to match `url('/pix/ajax/ajax-loader (2).gif')`, as well as something more typical like `url(/assets/domainsbg@2x-0d8ea9b405f202ff135ced3cdb4658cc.png)`.  I've tapped out my limited regex abilities and could use some help.  The test cases I'm using are:

```css
background: url('/pix/ajax/ajax-loader (2).gif')
background: url(/pix/ajax/ajax-loader (2).gif)
background: url(/assets/domainsbg@2x-0d8ea9b405f202ff135ced3cdb4658cc.png)
background: url('/assets/domainsbg@2x-0d8ea9b405f202ff135ced3cdb4658cc.png')
background-image: url(file.gif);
background-image: url('file.gif') no-repeat;
background: #FF0000 url( "file.gif" ) no-repeat  ;
background: #FF0000 url( "file%20space.gif" ) no-repeat;
```

FYI i know regex is problematic and parsing with it is generally not the best solution, but in this case i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The following Regex machtes all your test cases:

```
 url\(.*\)
```

btw: [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) is a good site to test your regex on the fly.

Comment: To clarify, the CSS must *not* be minified or contain multiple `url(...)` occurrences on the same line for this to work. RegEx does not work particularly well with nesting but in this case (and assuming properly formatted CSS), this should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^\s*background.*:.*url\((.+)\)/i);
console.log(regex.exec("background: url('/pix/ajax/ajax-loader (2).gif')")[1]);
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

This is very inelegant, but it should work to extract the URLs without the delimiters (i.e. without any single or double quotes):

```
url\((?:(?:\s*(?:'([^']+)'|"([^"]+)")\s*)|([^)]+))\)
```

You would extract any non-blank matches for groups `$1`, `$2`, or `$3`.

This works for all of your examples except this one:

```
background: url(/pix/ajax/ajax-loader (2).gif)
```

but for good reason, because that one has invalid syntax.